# How can can evanescent field cause fluorescence if there is no energy transport?

Tags: reflection, microscopy

I am currently looking at the topic "Total Internal Reflection Microscopy".
This creates an evanescent field travelling to my sample. This evanescent field no activates the Fluorophores. But how is this possible? If there is no energy transport what activates them? The process excites them, they will emit a photon and be in a higher vibrational state. So where does the energy come for this?

Comment: Your wording is unclear, but I suspect the answer is this:  when the evanescent field reaches a material of appropriate index of refraction, energy is in fact transferred across the "gap."

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of energy would suggest that the incident energy = internally reflected energy + evanescent energy